# domPDF background image is not rendering in the PDF

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, dompdf

```
<?php

include('../helper/app2.php');

$admin = new admin;

$preview = $admin->pdfPreview();

$html = '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html><head><title> New Document </title><meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus"><meta name="Author" content=""><meta name="Keywords" content="">  <meta name="Description" content="">  <link href="../../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></head><body><div class="biegeBox"><div class="cardContainer"><div class="cardImg" style="background-image:url(http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/demo/'. $preview[0]['image'].'); background-repeat:no-repeat;"><div class="cardQuote">'.$preview[0]['desc'].'</div></div></div></div></body></html>';

if ( isset( $html ) ) {

    require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->set_paper($_POST["paper"], $_POST["orientation"]);
    $dompdf->render();

    $dompdf->stream("dompdf_out.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));

    exit(0);
}
?>
```

The above code I am using to create pdf from dom, but its not rendering image in the pdf. Can any one help me to fix it. After reading this  [DOMPDF Page background (or alternatives?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910187/dompdf-page-background-or-alternatives) question and answer I changed the background property.

Comment: Make sure your setting for accessing remote resources are correct, specifically DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE and allow_url_fopen are both true. Using dompdf 0.5.x or 0.6.x? In 0.6.x you can access dompdf/www/setup.php (via your web server) to look for any red flags.

Comment: yes both DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE and allow_url_fopen is true and enabled.

Comment: Can you post the resulting HTML+CSS rather than the PHP that generates it? Is your containing div styled with a width/height? Which version of dompdf are you using?

Comment: In my case, `allow_url_fopen` needed to be turned on from PHP.ini.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to give Background to pdf by dompdf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994460/how-to-give-background-to-pdf-by-dompdf)

Answer (score 0):

This may not apply to you fully, but in my shared hosting environment the only way i was able to include images was to have the image in the same directory as the HTML file and refer to it via its relative path